# How can I ensure an id remains defined after changes to the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to create an app that can add, edit, and delete "facts" in a table, adapted from an example to-do list program. I use an id number to create a unique key for each td item, and attach it to a variable called `todoItem`. This is all well and good. Adding and editing items works perfectly well.

However, when I try to delete an item (by splicing out a specific index in my array), `todoItem` becomes `undefined`. Something in the deletion function is also deleting the `todoItem` variable. This means that after deleting an item, I can't add more items and get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` error if I try to add one. There's no reference to `todoItem` in my deletion function, so I don't understand how it's getting deleted.

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
 const deleteList = todos.map((oneTodo) => {
   if (oneTodo.id === id) {
     console.log("id "+id);
     oneTodo = todos.splice(id, 1);
   }
   return oneTodo;
 });
 console.log(deleteList);
 setTodos(deleteList);
 console.log("todo, id:"+todo, id);
 console.log("length: "+todos.length);
};
```

I am also getting an `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of FactsHandler.` error after running the deletion function (and not the add/edit functions). I suspect this is caused by the former problem, as I use the `todoItem.id` to define a key for each item; if it's missing, a key can't be defined.

The code I'm writing is quite lengthy and a bit messy, so I'm adding the full code as pastebins. I'm thinking it could possibly be something else in my program, but I don't know where or what that would be. Any help would be appreciated. I've poured over this code for several hours this evening and haven't gotten anywhere.

FactsHandler (main function) https://pastebin.com/UzUpNyjK

Item (item component) https://pastebin.com/fncrRfDA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript `array.map()` doesn't work the way you used it. you are supposed to return a new item for each element of the array

YOu can use javascript `array.filter()` method for this purpose

```
const deleteList = todos.filter((oneTodo) => oneTodo.id !== id );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const index = todos.indexOf(todo => todo.id === id);
    if (index !== -1) {
        todos.splice(index, 1);
        setTodos([...todos]);
    }    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are using the wrong list operator (`map`) when you should be using `filter`:

```js
const list = [
  { id: "apple", label: "Apple" },
  { id: "banana", label: "Banana" }
];
const deleteItem = (itemId) => list.filter(({ id }) => id !== itemId);
deleteItem("apple") // => [{id: 'banana', label: 'Banana'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to properly remove the object from the array. A reference of the same can be taken from [here](https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-remove-from-array/).
Easiest ways, I found are:

1. Using conditional for loop,
2. Using Array.splice()

Ex.

```
let todos = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ABC"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "DEF"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "GHI"
},]; 
const id = 1;

// Approach 1
for(let i =0; i < todos.length; i++){
   if(todos[i].id === id){
       todos.splice(i, 1);
       break;
   }
}

// Approach 2
todos = todos.filter((oneTodo) => oneTodo.id !== id );

console.log('Updated todos:', todos);
```